# Unsupported characters for the charset 'ISO-8859-1' in Spring Res file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, locale

I am trying to implement localization in my spring boot project. And it fine work in some language like  `Locale.ITALIAN` ,`Locale.GERMAN`. In case of

> Malayalam , Tamil and Hindi

getting "???" in api response. Here I am sharing my code and screen shots

**Application class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JavaI18nSpringBootApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JavaI18nSpringBootApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Bean
    public CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter() {
        final CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return characterEncodingFilter;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HelloController {

@Autowired
private LocaleResolver localeResolver;

@Autowired
Messages messages;

@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
@Autowired
private HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse;
@GetMapping("/test")
@ResponseBody
public String test() {
    return  messages.get("hello");

}
```

**Message class**

```
    @Component
public class Messages {
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    private MessageSourceAccessor accessor;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        Locale l = new Locale("ml", "IN");
        accessor = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource, l);
    }

    public String get(String code) {
        return accessor.getMessage(code);
    }

}
```

[image]

**application.properties**

[image]

Comment: I think you should change the file-encoding to fix this. The file encoding of the application.properties.

Comment: @AbuBakarKhan already tried that
input.encoding=utf-8
output.encoding=utf-8

Comment: no i mean the properties file itself

Answer (score 8):

if first answer didnt helped with showing messages

In intellij idea go to: File->Settings->Editor->File Encoding and mark transparent native
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In intellij idea go to: File->Settings->Editor->File Encoding, and change 'default encoding for properties files' to UTF-8